# Writing a nested list into a text file?

Tags: python

Hey guys python newbie here, if I were to run the below code:

```
test = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in test:
        for i in range(2):
            file.write("%s" % item)
            file.write("\n")
```

the text file looks like:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Any help on how I can make it look like this:

```
a    b    c
a    b    c
a    b    c
a    b    c
```

thanks in advance and please feel free to correct my coding.

Comment: the inner for loop should be len(item) and you want to write item[i]. This way you are writing every item. The "\n" should be "\t" to be a tab rather than a newline. Then outside the second loop, you should put "\n" to have a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have tabs between each item rather than newlines. The second thing I change is I added `file.write("\n")` after the inner loop, in order to have a new line between each row. Finally I added `file.close()` to close the file.

```
test = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in test:
        for i in range(len(item)):
            file.write("%s" % item[i])
            file.write("\t") # having tab rather than "\n" for newline. 
        file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: join is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use [`''.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join('  '.join(item) for item in test))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, lett)) for lett in test))
```

The code turns the list into a string with `join`, then separates the lines by joining them with a `\n`.

The output is this:

```
a b c
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

It looks like you wanted tabs, so you can join with `\t` instead of `' '`:

```
test = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, sl)) for sl in test))
```

Which outputs this:

```
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
```